# xpages efficient view picker

Tags: view, xpages, picker

Im looking for a efficient view picker solution. My requirement is that I need to make a viewpicker available for selection to the users. However, there are more than 10000 documents in that view. For eg. List of all customers for a company.

The solution I tried is taking too long to load. Would appreciate if somebody can spare a thought on this.

Comment: _What is the solution that you tried?_ If you have extension library then look into Value Picker. If not then from OpenNTF you have [View Picklist Custom Control](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=View%20Picklist%20Custom%20Control) and [XPages Multi Select Dialog Control](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/ProjectLookup/XPages%20Multi%20Select%20Dialog%20Control).

Answer (score 0):

Santosh,
you first need to go back to the UX drawing board. No user wants to scroll through a list of 10000 customers. Test (using paper mockups, not code) different approaches for the UX. Type-ahead or "my favorite" list and an FTSearch to add accounts, a preselection by location or type.

Design the principles, so users can get their work done fast. Very important: don't ask for opinions, but let user interact with your mockups, so they ACT and EXPERIENCE how it feels like.

Once that's settled you can wonder about making the selected method(s) fast.